# How to migrate to socket.io 0.9.16 from socket.io 1.2?

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I have this code written in Socket.io 1.2

```
var app=require('express')();
var http=require('http').Server(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(http);
var room;
var messageEmitted;;
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname +'/index.html');
});
app.get('/lol', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname +'/lol.html');
});
io.use(function(socket,next){
    var handShakeData=socket.request;
    room=handShakeData._query['roomName'];
    messageEmitted=handShakeData._query['messageText'];
    next();
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('A user connnected on : '+room);
    socket.join(room);
    io.to(room).emit('emittedMessages',messageEmitted);
    console.log(messageEmitted);
    /*socket.on('emittedMessages',function(msg){
        //socket.emit(msg); // Send message to sender
        socket.broadcast.emit(msg); // Send message to everyone BUT sender
    });*/
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // io.to(room).emit('emittedMessages','A User Disconnected on: '+room);
        console.log('A user disconnected');
    });     
});


http.listen(3000,function(){
   console.log('Listening oon Port: 3000');
});
```

And this code works perfectly fine.

I am trying to access this code from android library called [Gottox](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) and this version requires 0.9.16

However when I try to move to old library i.e. 0.9.16 by typing the commands below:

> `npm remove socket.io`
>
> `npm install socket.io@0.9.16`

When I run:

> `node server.js`

I get this error:

```
D:\NodeJSSocketBroadcast>node server.js

D:\NodeJSSocketBroadcast\server.js:3
var io=require('socket.io')(http);
                           ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\NodeJSSocketBroadcast\server.js:3:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

How do I implement the same in older version of socket.io? I cannot find any documenatation. I also found [this link](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1364) describing the same.

Please help.! :( :(

Answer (score 0):

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(1337);`
```

But i recommend using https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java - java implementation supporting socket.io 1.2.1